# How to prevent firing triggers by roll up summary fields

Tags: trigger, roll-up-summary, childrecords, parent

I have some roll up summary fields on parent object(account) to a child object (opportunities). When I make any changes on opportunities, roll up summary fields are automatically updated, and it fires account triggers, but I dont want any  changes on account.

How can I prevent it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can apply check in account trigger like `!isChanged(RollupsummryField)`.When this condition would be true then only operations define in the trigger would happen.`IsChanged()` here means comparing the value of that field from old records with new records.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I may recommend you is to create specific conditions on the Account trigger (Handler/Service whatever you use for to split logic). For examle - run trigger logic only when Account specific field has been updated, WebSite for example. So, after running triggers by roll up summaries the logic will not run, because your WebSite did not changed.
Hope this help you.